# JavaScript variables question (variable equals x if it exists otherwise equals y)

Tags: javascript, variables, lua

so I come from a Lua/XML background and am moving into HTML/CSS/JavaScript and am a little stumped on what I'm guessing is something fairly simple. I'll just give an example in Lua of what I'm trying to do in JavaScript.

```
local a = "text"
local b = c or a
```

As simple as: if variable c doesn't exist use variable a

Comment: _"if variable c doesn't exist..."_ - then you cannot "use" it without producing a [`ReferenceError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) -> [ReferenceError: "x" is not defined - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all variable `c` needs to be defined somewhere otherwise it makes an error. after that
You can use ternary operator:

```
let a = 'text';
let b = typeof c == 'undefined' ? c : a;
```

here are some links for you to check:

https://mkyong.com/javascript/check-if-variable-is-exists-in-javascript/

https://guide.freecodecamp.org/c/ternary-operator/

Comment: @Andreas you're right about the string but typeof works with parentheses too

Comment: Yes, therefor I'd written _"unnecessary"_ and not _"wrong"_ ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 'text';
var b = (typeof(c)==undefined)?c:a;
console.log(b);
```

Comment: `typeof` returns a string, hence `typeof(c) == undefined` will always be false

Comment: if varibale c is not defined. then how it will return type as string ?
Can you explain me in brief in below link.
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/5ucL7g4d/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#Errors